# How do I consume files in Django 2.2 for yaml parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml, django-2.2

I'm trying to upgrade my site from Django 1.11 to Django 2.2, and I'm having trouble with uploading and parsing yaml files.

The error message is:

> ScannerError : mapping values are not allowed here in "", line 1, column 34: b'---\n recipeVersion: 9\n name: value\n'
>   ^

I'm getting the file contents using a ModelForm with a widget defined as:

```
'source': AsTextFileInput()
```

... using ...

```
class AsTextFileInput(forms.widgets.FileInput):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return files.get(name).read()
```

... and then I get the source variable to parse with:

```
cleaned_data = super(RecipeForm, self).clean()
source = cleaned_data.get("source")
```

From that error message above, it looks like my newlines are being escaped, so yaml sees the text all on a single line. I tried logging the source of this file, and here's how it shows in my log file:

> DEBUG b'---\n  recipeVersion: 9\n  name: value\n'

So, how can I get this file content without (what looks to me like) escaped newlines so I can parse it as yaml?

Edit: my code and yaml (simplified for this question) have not changed; upgrading Python projects has broken the parsing.

Comment: I don't think the newlines are escaped, that's an artifact of printing them (see also the `b` before the string). Are you sure the YAML is completely correct?

Comment: Are you, or have you considered, using [`pyyaml`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I used a subset of my yaml in my question, and that works from a Django shell: In [14]: yaml.full_load("""---
    ...:   recipeVersion: 9
    ...:   name: value
    ...: """)
Out[14]: {'recipeVersion': 9, 'name': 'value'}

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Yes, I'm using PyYAML==5.1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decoding the bytestring fixed it:

```
class AsTextFileInput(forms.widgets.FileInput):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return files.get(name).read().**decode('utf-8')**
```